# How do I make two copies of the same AngularJS application navigate independently using UI.Router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to make two copies of the **same** AngularJS application co-exist peacefully on the same page at the same time while having them be able to operate, route, independently.

I've gotten the two applications to work at the same time, on the same page using a combination of angular.bootstrap and giving them individual application names. However, when a link is clicked in one application they both route to the same place.

**app.js**

```
function bootstrap(id) {
    'use strict';
    /* App Module */

    var viewName = id + 'view';

    var $urlRouterProviderRef = null;
    var $stateProviderRef = null;

    var app = angular.module(id, [
        'core',
        'widgets',
        'directives',
        /*
         * Feature Areas
         */
        'layout',
        'barChartExample',
        'dataTableExample'
    ]);

    app
        .config(config);

    var states = [{
        "name": "barChartExample",
        "url": "/",
        "views": [{
            'name': viewName,
            'templateUrl': '/angularjs-boilerplate-portlet/app//barchart-example/barchart-example.html',
            'controller': 'BarChartExampleCtrlAs',
            'controllerAs': 'vm'
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "dataTableExample",
        "url": "/dataTableExample",
        "views": [{
            'name': viewName,
            'templateUrl': '/angularjs-boilerplate-portlet/app/datatable-example/datatable-example.html',
            'controller': 'DataTableExampleCtrlAs',
            'controllerAs': 'vm'
        }]
    }];

    config.$inject = ['$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider'];

    function config($locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) { 
        $urlRouterProviderRef = $urlRouterProvider;

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
        $stateProviderRef = $stateProvider;
    }

    app.run(['$state',
        function($state) {
            angular.forEach(states, function(value, key) {
                var state = {
                    "url": value.url,
                    "views": {}
                };
                angular.forEach(value.views, function(view) {
                    state.views[view.name] = {
                        templateUrl: view.templateUrl,
                    };
                });

                $stateProviderRef.state(value.name, state);
            });
            $state.go("barChartExample");
        }
    ]);

    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById(id), [id]);
}
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="App1"
     class="container-fluid" >

    <div data-ng-include="'/angularjs-boilerplate-portlet/app/layout/topnav.html'"></div>

    <div data-ui-view="App1view"></div>

</div>

<script>
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        bootstrap('App1');
    });
</script>
```

**topnav.html**

```
<div class="navbar" data-ng-controller="TopNavCtrl as vm">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="#">{{vm.title}}</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>
                <a ui-sref="barChartExample" ui-sref-active="active">Bar Chart Example</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a ui-sref="dataTableExample" ui-sref-active="active">DataTable Example</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the use case for this?

Comment: Angular based liferay portlets

Comment: No, I meant why do you need to use 2 angularjs environments on the same page?

Comment: So these apps will live inside portlets - basically mini-applications you can drag and drop onto a page within a portal CMS - and you can make a portlet be instancable. So, I was wondering if you could have instancable applications that navigate independently.